# Elasticsearch update in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch lib for java (org.elasticsearch) and I was using version 1.4.4. Now I'm upgrading everything to the latest one and changing the code.

I had this

```
SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareMoreLikeThis(AUCTION_INDEX, AUCTION_PRODUCT_DOCUMENT, productId + "").setSearchSize(size).setField("name").setMinDocFreq(0)

                    .setMinTermFreq(1).setMinWordLen(1).setSearchSource(query).execute().actionGet();
```

But now I don't have the prepareMoreLikeThis in version 5.4. What I can do to replace this and still have the same result?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-specialized-queries.html#java-query-dsl-mlt-query

Comment: But for my example I only have the original id entry. I want "more like that" is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [More Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).

Use `QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery`

Comment: Like this: 

Item item = new Item(AUCTION_INDEX, AUCTION_PRODUCT_DOCUMENT, productId + "");
            Item[] items = {item};
            MoreLikeThisQueryBuilder mltQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery(items).minDocFreq(0).minTermFreq(1).minWordLength(1); 
            SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch(AUCTION_INDEX).setTypes(AUCTION_PRODUCT_DOCUMENT).setSize(size).setQuery(mltQueryBuilder).setPostFilter(range)
                    .execute().get();